# Do allergists treat non allergic sensitivities?

Tags: nutrition, allergy, general-practitioners

Do allergists treat non allergic sensitivities such as (non-celiac) Gluten Intolerance?

This question is so trivial that I didn't find any source to add to it and I hope it can be accepted here as an exception (I have added sources to any question I have ever asked here). It may be that this question should be migrated for another Stack Exchange website.

Comment: Really broad question. Which allergists? All of them? Everywhere in the world? I think the answer is: _if they choose to do so._ A licensed MD is legally free to practice almost anything, at least in the US. On a practical level there are limits, but I don't believe there's any reason why an allergist can't treat anything they encounter that they're comfortable treating.

Comment: I did mean to ask about all of them all over the world, but I because people in my country and other countries like to imitate the U.S I guess an answer about the US would be something for most people to go with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non allergic sensitivity turns to be a very broad term, too broad to even cover psychological situations. Nutritional sensitivities that don't cause an immunological problem are not likely to be treated by allergists or immunologists.

The "About" section in the website of the American Academy of Allergy, Asthma and Immunology (AAAAI)<sup>[(1)](https://www.aaaai.org/About/About-Allergists-Immunologists)</sup> doesn't mention anything outside the scopes of allergy medicine or immunology.

> An allergist / immunologist (commonly referred to as an allergist) is a physician specially trained to diagnose, treat and manage allergies, asthma and immunologic disorders including primary immunodeficiency disorders. These conditions range from the very common to the very rare, spanning all ages and encompassing various organ systems.

In the "About" section in the website of the British Society for Allergy and Clinical Immunology (BSACI) doesn't mention anything outside the scopes of allergy medicine or immunology as well<sup>[(2)](https://www.bsaci.org/about-bsaci/who-are-bsaci/)</sup>.

---

If nutritional intolerance isn't causing an allergy or an immunity problem but rather another problem, then in general, depending on what that problem is, another field of expertise would be suitable.
An allergist / immunologist might be able (or not disallowed) to try to treat such patient's intolerance but that's unlikely that he will.

Comment: +1, though you might be mistaken about what proctologists do. Constipation would be treated by a gastroenterologist. Proctologists really focus on (more serious and localized) problems of the distal colon, rectum and anus (in the US), e.g. rectal cancer, pruritus ani, fecal incontinence, etc. However, as both you and @CareyGregory mention, physicians treat what they're comfortable treating and some overlap is to be expected. A further consideration is what specialties are available where. A general surgeon might care for a rectal cancer patient when a proctologist is unavailable.

Comment: I agree with you 99% It was good to mention general surgeons. I talked about colorectal surgery only in regards to fecal impaction which happen to require manual removal (not necessarily with surgery but by pulling off when the patient folds his body in a uterus-fassion.

Comment: The direction this has taken is a bit uncomfortable (for both the poor patient and the poor physician... but any physician can do a digital disimpaction, and most have. Heck, even nurses can do it in most jurisdictions. I don't know why you feel the need to be so specific; the OP was about Allergists and sensitivities and now "the OP" seems to be opining on many aspects of medicine (in error at least in the US.) Errors in answers isn't good, even though these are relatively minor.

Comment: How was I "so specific" and the OP did include reference to Gluten intolerance hence the talk about possible constipation.